# Pass a prop to every child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to pass a prop containing a function to any child ? More precisely I would like to pass a function from a  component to every {children} component :

```
<>
    <Navbar />
    <main>{children}</main>
    <Footer />
</>
```

Comment: You may be interested in [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Sure, I completly forgot about this ... I'm used to use Redux in other projects, but I forgot I could use Context API to do this. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should then use something like [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for that.

The props you pass to your `Context Provider` will be available to all it's children. But you won't get them via `props`, you need to get them via the `Context Consumer`.

But the good thing is [Context Consuming hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) are available to make it easy to do so.